# Unable to read the text from a TextBox` within a `Repeater`

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, repeater

I am not getting any errors but I am unable to get the value from a `TextBox`.

This is my VB code for reading the `TextBox` value:

```
Private Sub btn_Save_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handlesbtn_Save.Click       
    For Each item As RepeaterItem In Article_Block_Migrated.Items
        Dim txtField As Label = item.FindControl("Article_Number")
        Dim a = txtField.Text

        Dim txtField1 As TextBox = DirectCast(item.FindControl("txt_DWPDate"), TextBox)
        Dim b = txtField1.Text
    Next
End Sub
```

This is my ASP code for the `Repeater`:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Article_Block_Migrated" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox Width="80px" ID="txt_DWPDate" runat="server" MaxLength="50"></asp:TextBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: You are not able because your PC explodes or what happens? If you get an error, please tell it us because you want us to fix it :)

Comment: Please provide a proper [mcve]. I'm guessing there is text in the `TextBox` to be read but that's the issue here, I'm guessing. Can you please try and provide more information on this.

Comment: "not able to" means what? If you don't get an error, then precisely what happens instead? Does it find the (correct) textbox? What value is there instead? Have you actually stepped through this yourself with a debugger and watched the variables?

Comment: "not able to" means, I am getting blank value from this textbox on click of save button.

Comment: Have you placed a breakpoint, debugged, and checked if txtField1 is not null? If it isn't, have you checked its properties? (besides .Text)

Comment: `Dim txtField As Label = item.FindControl("Article_Number")` ... this will return null because there's no such control in your code sample, and then `Dim a = txtField.Text` should be causing an exception because  `txtField` is null.